# How to process JPEG-XR files in Pillow (or generally in Python) in linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-imaging-library, jpeg-xr

[JPEG XR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XR) is a Microsoft developed format.

On Ubuntu 14.04, I installed

```
sudo apt-get install libjxr-dev
sudo apt-get install libjxr-tools
```

and now I can at least convert the `*.jxr` files into other more friendly formats like bitmap or tif, with

```
JxrDecApp -i in.jxr -o output.bmp -c 0
```

or just using (ImageMagick)

```
convert in.jxr output.tif
```

However, Pillow still won't read the jxr image:

```
from PIL import Image
img =  Image.open('in.jxr', 'rb')
```

gives `IOError: cannot identify image file 'in.jxr'`.

(it has no problem with the `out.tif` of course).

I rebuilt Pillow (with `--no-cache-dir` after installing the `libjxr-dev` lib too by the way).

I also tried using [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/), but despite the ImageMagick `convert` command working, Wand won't read the file (possibly because ImageMagick just delegates this task to JxrDecApp anyway).

Finally, I tried `imageio`, with `im = imageio.imread('my.jxr')`, and it also failed to read the file.

Is there anyway I can process these JXR images in Pillow? Or any way at all in Python for that matter? I'm stuck calling convert with a subprocess at the moment..

Comment: I don't think Pillow supports JPEG-XR. if you are using imageio, please notice that it uses the freeimage library, and a bug was carelessly introduced in the Debian/Ubuntu package that breaks support for jxr and other formats. http://git.net/ml/general/2016-10/msg21901.html